# How to remove a list of length 1 from a nested list in lisp?

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists

I have a nested list (1 (4 (5) 3) 9 10) and I want to delete the lists of length 1 so the result would be (1 (4 3) 9 10).
This is what I have tried so far, which does not remove (5) and returns the original list.

```
(defun remove (l)
(cond
    ((null l) nil)   
    ((and (listp (car l)) (= (length l) 1)) (remove (cdr l)))   
    ((atom (car l)) (cons (car l) (remove (cdr l))))
    (T (cons (remove (car l)) (remove (cdr l))))   
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: first, `remove` is a predefined function in package CL, so I strongly advice to use a different name, let's say `my-remove`.
Second, you are testing the length of `l` instead of the sublist `(car l)`, which is what you want to eliminate.
The correct form would be:

```
(defun my-remove (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)   
    ((and (listp (car l)) (= (length (car l)) 1)) (my-remove (cdr l)))   
    ((atom (car l)) (cons (car l) (my-remove (cdr l))))
    (T (cons (my-remove (car l)) (my-remove (cdr l))))   
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tail call recursive version. Plus: Without the test `(atom (car l))` to be permissive for non-list and non-atom components in the list. (e.g. vectors or other objects as element of the list - they are treated like atoms.

```
(defun my-remove (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((listp (car l)) (if (= 1 (length (car l)))         ;; list objects
                             (my-remove (cdr l) acc)        ;; - of length 1     
                             (my-remove (cdr l) (cons (my-remove (car l)) acc)))) ;; - longer
        (t (my-remove (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc)))))        ;; non-list objects
```